use proxmox services without logging, possible?
i want to know if it is possible to use proxmox services without logging, i mean without connect a keyboard and a display. I remark that when i reboot my hypervisor, many time i was forced to launch manually services like ssh server and web server, i think its a waste of time. I could "enable" services to ultimately start them automatically.

ChatGPT is a horrible tool to correct grammar. It’s best to avoid apologizing for bad grammar instead of just correcting it.
Services can be configured to automatically launch when a system is rebooted

Yes, Proxmox VE can run headless.

thank you for your responses i apprecied ;)
